# Dirichlet Process as a Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Hello there,

I have problems understanding how a dirichlet process is in fact a stochastic process; a random variable which changes over t \in T. What is the T here, is it the partitions of the sample space which can grow to infinity?

I would appreciate any explanations :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could try good old [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process) on this...

Comment: If Wikipedia's page is the standard explanation, then this is a fantastic question. In fact, I would love to see a tutorial on DPs for the mathematician that has mastered the basics of measure-theoretic probability.

Comment: @Neil, I have no idea whether you formulated this request for real or as a jest but if you did ask seriously, a starting point could be the seminal paper *Prior distributions on spaces of probability measures* by T.S. Ferguson (Annals of Statistics, 1974). For a diversified and more recent list of references, see http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/porbanz/talks/npb-tutorial.html